# morris.js - month names (2014 Jan) instead of 2014-01

Tags: morris.js

I want to show my x labels as "2014 Jan", for example, instead of "2014-01".

The json of my data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "product1": 2,
    "product2": 0,
    "period": "2013-05"
  },
...
```

Comment: Does anyone know why **xLabelFormat** and **dateFormat** can't be used in a **bar chart**? Here above code don't work...

Comment: Neither xLabelFormat or dateFormat work for BAR charts, only LINE (at least for now). There is a GitHub thread here about it: https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/494

Answer (score 11):

OP found the solution using `xLabelFormat` and `dateFormat`:

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'morris-line-chart',
    data: <?php echo $morris_line_json; ?>,
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['product1', 'product2'],
    labels: ['Product 1', 'Product 2'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    xLabelAngle: 70,
    xLabelFormat: function (x) {
        var IndexToMonth = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez" ];
        var month = IndexToMonth[ x.getMonth() ];
        var year = x.getFullYear();
        return year + ' ' + month;
    },
    dateFormat: function (x) {
        var IndexToMonth = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez" ];
        var month = IndexToMonth[ new Date(x).getMonth() ];
        var year = new Date(x).getFullYear();
        return year + ' ' + month;
    },
    resize: true
});
```

Comment: change `return year + ' ' + month;` to `return month + ' ' + year;` to get `Mar 2013` format. Thanks for posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case of a **bar chart**, be careful because the object in argument of xLabelFormat is not a Date !

```js
xLabelFormat: function (x) {
  x.src; // this is all the data
  x.src.date; // this is probably what you are looking for
              // depends how you provided it, but it's probably a string and not a Date object
}
```

*Tested with version 0.5.1*